# A problem about coefficients of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Given $n \in \mathbb{N},$ let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials
$P:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of degree less than or equal to $n$

(i) Given $P \in V,$ let $\|P\|:=\max \left\{\left|a_{0}\right|, \ldots,\left|a_{n}\right|\right\},$ where $P(t)=a_{0}+$
$\cdots+a_{n} t^{n}, t \in[0,1] .$ Prove that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm in $V$

(ii) Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and $P \in V$ be such that $\|P\|_{L^{p}([0,1])} \leq 1$. Prove that there exists a constant $c=c(n)>0$ such that $\left|a_{k}\right| \leq c$ for all $k=1, \ldots, n .$ Hint: The vector space $V$ has finite dimension $n$

It is easy to prove i.But ii  is really difficult for me,I have proved that V has finite dimension, But I don't know how to use it.Can someone give me a more detailed hint?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the definition of the $L^p$-norm. It is about the integral, compute it for a polynomial $P$. And form the inequality norm$\le 1$. This is an inequality involving the coefficients of $P$. Then it is easy to deduce (ii).

Comment: In finite-dimensional spaces, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: @Professor Vector Excellent idea!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a finite-dimensional real or complex normed vector space then all norms on $X$ are uniformly equivalent: If $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ are norms for $X$ then there exist $c,d\in \Bbb R^+$ such that  for all $x\in X$
$$c\|x\|_a\le\|x\|_b\le d\|x\|_a.$$